# Can you use SLAM Gmapping in conjunction with AMCL Node?

Tags: localization, navigation, ros-kinetic, slam-gmapping, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I understand that AMCL node deals with robot localization. SLAM gmapping deals with Localization and mapping. Is there anyway to use AMCL node with SLAM gmapping to properly localize my robot in a map?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/323280/can-you-use-slam-gmapping-in-conjunction-with-amcl-node?/) by [StewartHemm74](https://answers.ros.org/users/39655/stewarthemm74/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2019-05-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe the Gmapping node just uses a particle filter with a fixed number of particles.  The pose estimate generated by the gmapping node is basically not published but internally estimates the position. To increase localization while mapping you can increase the particles at the cost of computation. AMCL basically works on a generated map and dynamically assigns particles based on KL Distance. Hope it helps.

---

Originally posted by [A_Hari](https://answers.ros.org/users/41462/a_hari/) with karma: 51 on 2019-05-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [StewartHemm74](https://answers.ros.org/users/39655/stewarthemm74/) on 2019-05-16**:
Thanks! where would I increase the particles if I'm using a lidar for scanning information?

**Comment by [A_Hari](https://answers.ros.org/users/41462/a_hari/) on 2019-05-16**:
A parameter called "particles" in the gmapping node can increase the number of particles in the particle filter.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

AMCL needs a map in order to localize the robot. A common tactic is using gmapping to create this map, save it using map_server, and then serve it to AMCL.

[You can find a tutorial about how to create and save a map here](http://wiki.ros.org/slam_gmapping/Tutorials/MappingFromLoggedData), just use you real robot data instead of a bagfile.

---

Originally posted by [SleepyTurtle](https://answers.ros.org/users/39792/sleepyturtle/) with karma: 30 on 2019-05-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [StewartHemm74](https://answers.ros.org/users/39655/stewarthemm74/) on 2019-05-16**:
Thanks! What about localization using SLAM Gmapping?

**Comment by [SleepyTurtle](https://answers.ros.org/users/39792/sleepyturtle/) on 2019-05-17**:
I'm sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean, Are you asking how to improve localization during SLAM or how to do localization with a map?

**Comment by [StewartHemm74](https://answers.ros.org/users/39655/stewarthemm74/) on 2019-05-17**:
How to improve localization during SLAM. I'm trying to navigate the robot in an unknown area using SLAM gmapping.

**Comment by [Danny_PR2](https://answers.ros.org/users/44786/danny_pr2/) on 2020-03-20**:
I think on that case you should actually improve your odometry. For example, if you have multiple sensors, e.g., encoder, IMU, you could use the robot localization package and output a filtered odometry, which in turn it can be used as an input to Gmapping. Once you have better odometry, Gmapping shall provide better SLAM results which include the localization w.r.t the map and mapping.